# Esri Developer Api

Tags: javascript

Trying to get data from popup attribute table into html element as value. Where the code below brings an array into the popup as content, i want to bring just one piece of that data into an input element as text i.e from the code below fieldinfos, fieldName: "name". Name is one of the attribute columns from the attribute table of the map, i want to use that in separate query (which i know how to do). Sorry, I'm a real novice with javascript. Any help greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>
      Custom popup actions per feature attribute | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for
      JavaScript 4.26
    </title>

    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #viewDiv {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/"></script>

    <script>
      require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"], (
        Map,
        MapView,
        FeatureLayer
      ) => {
        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
        });

        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          center: [-101.94981250000075, 41.20977753557709],
          zoom: 5
        });

        /********************
         * Add feature layer
         ********************/
        // sampling of breweries
        const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
          url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/OpenBeerDB/FeatureServer/0",
          popupTemplate: {
            title: "{name}",
            lastEditInfoEnabled: false,
            actions: [
              {
                id: "find-brewery",
                image:
                  "https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-custom-action/live/beer.png",
                title: "Brewery Info"
              }
            ],
            content: [
              {
                type: "fields",
                fieldInfos: [
                  {
                    fieldName: "name"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "address1",
                    label: "address"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "city"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "state"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "phone"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "website"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        });

        map.add(featureLayer);

        view.when(() => {
          // Watch for when features are selected
          view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", (graphic) => {
            if (graphic) {
              // Set the action's visible property to true if the 'website' field value is not null, otherwise set it to false
              const graphicTemplate = graphic.getEffectivePopupTemplate();
              graphicTemplate.actions.items[0].visible = graphic.attributes
                .website
                ? true
                : false;
            }
          });

          const popup = view.popup;
          popup.viewModel.on("trigger-action", (event) => {
            if (event.action.id === "find-brewery") {
              const attributes = popup.viewModel.selectedFeature.attributes;
        document.getElementById("name") = "test";

              // Get the 'website' field attribute
              const info = attributes.website;
              // Make sure the 'website' field value is not null
              if (info) {
                // Open up a new browser using the URL value in the 'website' field
                window.open(info.trim());
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="viewDiv" class="esri-widget" style="width:600px;height:600px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding "console.log(graphic.attributes.city);" to the below section of code i am now able to query the underlying esri attribute data and bring that into an input and use it in further querying:

```
       view.when(() => {
            // Watch for when features are selected
            view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", (graphic) => {
                if (graphic) {
                    // Set the action's visible property to true if the 'website' field value is not null, otherwise set it to false
                    const graphicTemplate = graphic.getEffectivePopupTemplate();
                    graphicTemplate.actions.items[0].visible = graphic.attributes
                        .website
                        ? trueraphi
                        : false;
                    console.log(graphic.attributes.city);
                    document.getElementById("test").value = graphic.attributes.city;
                }
            });
```